# why returning the same html tag attribute every time?

Tags: html, f#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to parse some data from some html using html agility. This is what the data looks like with many table rows:

```
<tr>
    <td><a href="showindex.cfm"><span class="style1">companies</span></a></td>
    <td><b>71</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>                      
    <font><b><a href="showindex.cfm">political situation</a></b></font></td>    
    <td><b>76</b></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
    <td><p title=" This is the political stability data;Score: 0.01;Sene:">
        <a href="showdatatable.cfm">political stability denge</a></p></td>
    <td> 7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p title="This index combines  policies.;Score: -0.34;Sene:">
        <a href="showdatatable.cfm">local government support</a></p></td>
    <td> 8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p title="This combines legal situation data;Score: 3.59;Sene:">
    <a href="showdatatable.cfm">legal situation</a></p></td>
    <td > 9</td>
</tr>
```

I made a sequence of the outer "td" tags.

What I am interested in is: For every table row extracting

1- if there is a "p" tag it's title attribute

2-Inner text of "a"

3- Inner text of the last "td" tags. and making them tuple,
like

```
(" This is the political stability data;Score: 0.01;Sene:", "companies", "71");
```

I make every two "td" tags a tuple first (my method maybe very crude sorry for that), then extract the data I am interested in.
This as my code

```
tdSeq:seq<HtmlNode>
tdSeq
|>Seq.pairwise
|>Seq.mapi(fun int item -> (int, item))
|>Seq.filter(fun (no, _) -> no%2 = 0)
|>List.ofSeq
|>List.map(fun (no, item ) -> item)
|>List.map(fun (a, b) ->

                   let data = a.InnerText.Trim() 
                   let value= b.InnerText.Trim()   
                   let title=
                       let p= a.SelectSingleNode("//p" )
                       if p.Attributes.["title"] <> null then
                            p.Attributes.["title"].Value
                       else
                            ""                          
                   (title, data, value))
```

My problem is for every tuple only the first "p" tag's title is returned.
Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with F#, but here is the C# equivalent:

```
HtmlDocument doc = LoadMyDocument();

foreach (HtmlNode tr in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("tr"))
{
    string title = null;
    HtmlNode titleNode = tr.SelectSingleNode(".//p");
    if (titleNode != null)
    {
        title = titleNode.GetAttributeValue("title", null);
    }

    string anchor = null;
    HtmlNode anchorNode = tr.SelectSingleNode(".//a");
    if (anchorNode != null)
    {
        anchor = anchorNode.InnerText;
    }

    string value = null;
    HtmlNode valueNode = tr.SelectSingleNode("td[last()]");
    if (valueNode != null)
    {
        value = valueNode.InnerText.Trim();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("title=" + title);
    Console.WriteLine("anchor=" + anchor);
    Console.WriteLine("value=" + value);
}
```

The main problem you have is because you use a "//p" expression which starts off root, instead of a ".//p" which starts from the current node.

Comment: Thanks, that was real helpful. I guess I must change the title.